# AJAX подгрузка изображений в админке Django

Tags: ajax, django, django-admin, upload

Поскажите приложение для Django, позволяющее в админке аплоадить картинку не перезагружая форму, с иконкой предпросмотра, с кнопками "добавить", "удалить", независимыми от "сохранить" внизу формы. Ну или что-то как медиатека ворпресса.

Django v2, Python 3

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте это приложение: [django-ajaximage](https://github.com/bradleyg/django-ajaximage).

Если оно не подойдет - можете попробовать использовать исходный код этого приложения для создания своего варианта загрузчика.

Comment: Да, спасибо, я уже так и сделал, форкнул и поправил, чтобы работала в новой джанге.

Comment: https://github.com/sergey-panasenko/django-ajaximage